# How to make pynput press return key, or some other line of code that presses return

Tags: python

After each 0 is typed, I want it so it'll press enter afterward, I've tried different lines but it didn't, I'm a complete beginner, pls help.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

import time

keyboard = Controller()

time.sleep(1)

for char in " 0 0 0 0 0 0 0":

 keyboard.press('0')

keyboard.release('0')

time.sleep(0.25)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pressing an `enter` with `pynput` is similar to what you have done, see [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Key.enter) from the docs. You would want to do something like the following.

```py
word = " 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
for i, char in enumerate(word):
    if char == "0":
      keyboard.press('0')
      keyboard.release('0')

    #last iteration
    if char == "0" and len(word)-1 == i:
       keyboard.press(Key.enter)
       keyboard.release(Key.enter)
       break #break the loop here
```